# Using Google AJAX Feed API Feedcontrol, I need a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-feed-api

I'm actually using the [jQuery Google Feed Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/gfeed/) to manually add some feeds to my site. One feed includes a photobucket album which I'd like to provide a preview of each image. I can't find a callback for the [FeedControl](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#FeedControl) class in the API documentation. Is there an better way to do this other than using a settimer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a request for this feature over in the [google ajax apis issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/list) since I don't think there is an answer to this question...

But, I may have found an alternative since I noticed that Google recently released their [Data Protocol APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) - hopefully it will find a better method there.